# Get the quotient when dividing a float in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to divide a float by an integer (like 3.87 / 2) and get a quotient (1 in my example).
How do I do this in python 2.7?

The '%' and '/' operators only work with integers

Comment: Also try `divmod(3.87,  2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about simply:

```
int(3.87 / 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
divisor = math.floor(3.875 / 2.0)
print(divisor)
#1.0
```

Alternative:

```
divisor = int(3.875 / 2)
print(divisor)
#1
```

Or (as mentioned by @Nizil)

```
divisor = 3.87 // 2
print(divisor)
#1.0
```

Comment: also, `int(3.87 / 2)` or (as said by vaultah) `3.87 // 2`